# Matrix power function in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

A quick question.

Have done some googling, but still cannot find the answer: what is the matrix power function in fortran (or is there any)?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no intrinsic matrix power function in Fortran.  There is the intrinsic `matmul` function for multiplying matrices which may be of assistance.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, I have just updated my code. It now works fine.